# iPad Floating Fixed Element Movement

Tags: jquery, ipad

I have a floating fixed div that moves on scroll (it's a menu bar on a website)...

I want that movement to not occur and it be fixed on the page if the user comes from iPad

The jQuery that handles that is something like:

```
(function ($) {
  // movement related stuff
});
```

How can I detect the user is coming from iPad and have that div be just normal on the page with no movement?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1)
    {
        $("#somediv").css("position","absolute");
    }
});
```

Hard to tell more without actual code or markup.